# how to get names of all detected models from existing tensorflow lite instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm looking to build a system that alerts me when there's a package at my front door. I already have a solution for detecting when there's a package (tflite), but I don't know how to get the array of detected objects from the existing tflite process and then pull out an object's title through the array. Is this even possible, or am I doing this wrong?
Also, the tflite model google gives does not know how to detect packages, but I'll train my own for that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a solution. I can just use the same array that the function that draws labels uses (`labels[int(classes[i])`) to get the name of the object in place `i` of the array (dunno if I'm using the correct terminology but whatever). hopefully this will help someone